# Compare time in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a program in PHP that will display a button for a subject . But I don't know the algorithm for if the schedule is 15 minutes before it starts.

eg. the subject will start 2:30 PM. The system will compare the current time, if the current time is 2:15 PM (15 minutes before the subject will start) the clickable button will display, else it shows a message for the time remaining.

```
$current_time = date('h:i A');
$time_start = date('h:i A', strtotime($r['time_start']));
$time_end = date('h:i A', strtotime($r['time_end']));

if( $current_time is 15 mins before $time_start && $current_time < $time_end){
  //show clickable button
}else{
  //show time remaining
}
```

[image]

Please help, the logic/algorithm is confusing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Datetime objects become really handy:

```
$time_start = new DateTime($r['time_start']);
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $time_start->diff($now);

if($diff->i < 15){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hey, yours worked so i picked your answer. Will you explain to me the line where $diff= $time_start -> diff($now) and how it can be compared it to 15?

Comment: DateTime objects have the method "diff". Basically when you call diff on an object and pass in another DateTime object as a parameter it will return you a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object. This contains information about the difference in the two dates as properties of the object. $diff->y is the difference in years, $diff->m is the difference in months etc...

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare strings, compare timestamps. [`time()`](https://www.php.net/time) is your friend.

```
$diff = time() - strtotime($r['time_start']);
if($diff < 0)
  ..too late, exam has started
elseif($diff > 15*60)
  ..more than 15 minutes remaining
else
  ..between 15 minutes and on time
```

Using [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) would also work but is just major overkill for simply comparing 2 basic timestamps.

Answer (score -1):

```
$time = time()
if(($time > strtotime("2:15pm")) && ($time < strtotime("2:30pm")){
    //Display button
}else{
    //Show time remaining
}
```